# How to add testing tools namespace to visual studio 2013 web express

Tags: c#, unit-testing, namespaces, automated-tests

I am trying to add the namespace Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting to use the assert class in my code. I've tried installing Microsoft.biz.testingtools from nugget packages but don't have the assert class available to use. I'm using visual studio web express and writing in c#.

Comment: Did you add the reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll in your project?

Comment: Hi Nick, I tried to use the namespace by adding it to the using list at the start of the code but it's not available for me to add. Sorry I'm a bit new to all this and not really sure about the dll?

Comment: Ok I right clicked on the project and clicked add and then found the correct reference to add to my project, the namespace is now available, thanks.

Comment: @A H: No problem. Glad it helped. Keep in mind that you can only import namespaces that are referenced in your project. Else the compiler would not know where to look for the namespace.

Comment: If you could add your comment as an answer I can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared the asked had forgotten to add the reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll to his project. The compiler is unable to find a imported namespace if you do not reference the project or dll where to find it.

You can add the reference to the UnitTestFramework.dll file by looking in your solution explore and right clicking on the 'reference' folder. Then choose 'Add Reference...'. The dll can be found under in Assemblies > Extensions in the form that opens.